# Add conditions using Contain

Tags: php, cakephp

I have following scenario:

Model 1 
Model 2

```
$this->Model1->find('all', 
      array('contain' => array('Model2' => array('conditions' => array('Model1.field > Model2.field')));
```

the above line of code is not working, can anyone help me finding the problem.
Please ignore syntax and just see the situation and tell me how can i do this
data of 2nd model is dependent on 1st model.

Comment: what do u mean code is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->Model1->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Model2' => array(
            'conditions' => array('Model1.field >' => 'Model2.field')
));
```

(notice breaking apart the `'Model1.field >'` and the `'Model2.field'`.

Also, make sure your model (Model1) has `$actsAs = array('Containable');`

Last minor note - better to use actual model/field names when asking your question - it helps solve your issue, and allows for advice if there's an easier/better way.

Comment: Thanks for being so specific :)

Comment: @user1217774 Dave is basically asking you what you meant by "error" :)